# Sublist into String Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sublist, coin-change

I have a little problem , I have this code and I need to convert the final print to a string, to be able to printthe final results in different lines and change the separator "," to a "+".
If someone could help me to fix this I will be grateful :D.

Thks in advance ^^.

Ex.:

Input: `7`

Output:

```
5 + 2

5 + 1 + 1

2 + 2 + 2 + 1

2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1

2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

Code:

```
def change(coins, amount)
      res = []
      def getchange(end, remain, cur_result):
        if end < 0: return
        if remain == 0:
            res.append(cur_result)
            return
        if remain >= coins[end]:
            getchange(end, remain - coins[end], cur_result + [coins[end]])
        getchange(end - 1, remain, cur_result)
    
     getchange(len(coins) - 1, amount, [])
     return res

q = int(input("Write your change: "))
st = change([1, 2, 5, 10], q)
print(st)
```

Comment: Please show the output of the current code and what you would like it to look like

Comment: I don't think that the function is needed for this example. Isn't this a question of changing a list such as `[1, 2, 3]` to `1 + 2 + 3`?

Comment: @tdelaney No, I believe the OP just wants to print the output of the function in a more user-friendly way.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Right. So you'd say that the function is an unnecessary distraction too?

Comment: @tdelaney Unnecessary, yes, but likely part of his assignment.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 - But its not needed for this question. That's the point. We want minimally reproducible examples so that questions are more generally useful for people searching for the tricks of the trade.

Comment: @tdelaney Oh, good point. I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your last line code from `print(st)` to

```
for s in st:
    print('+'.join((map(str,s))))
```

Comment: Bro, how you controled hahaha it works perfectly, thank you <3

Comment: Or, if you want spaces between each character, you can do `print(' + '.join((map(str,s))))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If `st` is a list of integers, you can change it to

```
print(" + ".join(str(s) for s in st))
```

Generators and comprehensions are generally preferred to the `map` operation.